# Pressing back button on Android to close/hide the keyboard is clearing my input field Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, back-button, input-field

I have two methods that fire the Unity Event for that input field, I'm trying to save the input field value into a variable and then give that value back to Input Field when back button is pressed, but it doesn't work on Android. It works just fine with Unity Editor

```
public string passwordHolder = "";

public void OnEditting()

    {
      if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) 
       {
         if (!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
          {
             passwordHolder = passwordText.text;
          }
      }
  }

public void OnEndEdit()
{

   if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) 
           {
               if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
               {              
                      passwordText.text = passwordHolder;               
               }
          }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The "Input" does not work as normal when the keyboard is open. So you can not do the check you do with the "ESC" / back button.

What I have done is creating a method to listen to an event of the keyboard status changing. If it is going to hide (Canceled), I keep the previous text in the field.

I add the script to the object with the InputField component and this is the code that I have put in "Start":

```
    inputField = gameObject.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
    inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(EndEdit);
    inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(Editing);
    inputField.onTouchScreenKeyboardStatusChanged.AddListener(ReportChangeStatus);
```

And this is the code of the methods:

```
private void ReportChangeStatus(TouchScreenKeyboard.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TouchScreenKeyboard.Status.Canceled)
        keepOldTextInField = true;
}

private void Editing(string currentText)
{
    oldEditText = editText;
    editText = currentText;
}

private void EndEdit(string currentText)
{
    if (keepOldTextInField && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldEditText))
    {
        //IMPORTANT ORDER
        editText = oldEditText;
        inputField.text = oldEditText;

        keepOldTextInField = false;
    }
}
```

It works for me and I hope it does for you aswell.